# How to start the snapcraft app?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I have sideloaded snapcraft java-hello-world app. I am wondering how to start the same. I have tried to invoke the wrapper in the shell and I get `java not found`.

```
(amd64)ubuntu@IndiaDevResSnappy3:/writable/system-data/apps/java-hello-world.sideload/current/bin$ sudo ./wrapper
./wrapper: 2: ./wrapper: java: not found
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which snapcraft version did you try? What steps did you take?

Comment: snapcraft --version
snapcraft (1.1.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, since you're using Snapcraft 1.x make sure you're running Snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04. You need to declare your binaries in the `snapcraft.yaml` ([example](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/blob/1.x/examples/opencv/snapcraft.yaml)). Once you've done that, upon install the binary will be available in your `$PATH` so you can just run it like:

```
$ <snap name>.<binary name>
```

So for the example I linked above, that would be:

```
$ opencv-example.example
```

Note that this is the same for Snappy Ubuntu Core 16.04/Snapcraft 2.x, but the syntax to declare the binaries changed ([same example, but for 16.04](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/blob/6685d6359887fbb7b1c35f3dce30bb70e7b06e8a/examples/opencv/snapcraft.yaml)).

Comment: I'm using the snap example https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/blob/1.x/examples/java-hello-world/snapcraft.yaml which has binaries declared. And I assume I need to invoke like "java-hello-world.hello" I also tried to invoke "java-hello-world.wrapper" but it did not worked. May be I'm missing something else.

Comment: Indeed, `java-hello-world.hello` should do it. What happens when you run that?

Comment: I see $ java-hello-world.hello
-bash: java-hello-world.hello: command not found 
Also the App is been installed
~$ snappy list
Name             Date       Version Developer
ubuntu-core      2015-08-28 1       ubuntu
java-hello-world 2016-03-24 0       sideload
ni-crio-snappy   2016-03-24 0       sideload

Comment: FYI, server version
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
Is there any constraint that I should have the same version of Ubuntu in the machine in which I build the sanp and the machine in which I install.

Comment: Check the /apps/bin directory. What's in there? (the binary should be)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I don't see the executable in the said path. 
writable/system-data/apps/bin$ ls
snappy-debug.security
So, I'm missing something not sure what I'm missing. Can you please help me out to figure out the issue.

Comment: I have figured out the issue it's basically because of the confusion that I made with the VM's, it's version and snapcraft's version. Now. I'm able to solve the issue and able to start as you said.

Comment: Could you please add the syntax for 15.10+ as 15.04 is EOL.

Comment: @Wilf as I said in the answer, the way you launch things hasn't changed. The `snap.yaml` and `snapcraft.yaml` syntax is the only thing that changed, and that wasn't part of the question (although I linked to an example if you're interested). If you have a question about the syntax, please [Ask One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!